# Conversion of Array to Strings

Tags: java, jsp

How to convert an array into String in JSP. Here, I am using the code :

```
 String str = a.toString();
```

after this, I  have to print that String too but if I try the output shows like ASCII values. Can you please help me?

Comment: show up what you have tried?

Comment: Try `java.util.Arrays.toString()` method

Comment: @user3694267 If I could downvote that comment I would. That code is broken and worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class StringUtils {
  private StringUtils() {}
  public static String arrayToString(String[] a, String separator) {
    if (a == null || separator == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    if (a.length > 0) {
        result.append(a[0]);
        for (int i=1; i < a.length; i++) {
            result.append(separator);
            result.append(a[i]);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(
         StringUtils.arrayToString(new String[] { "a" , "b", "c" } ,  ",")
         );    
  }
}
```

Also check [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) which:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
>   array.

```
int[] intArray={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String str = Arrays.toString(array);
System.out.print(str);
```

Comment: [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: You should probably rework this to put more emphasis on using the existing wheel *before* reinventing it...

Comment: Good one BackSlah..added in my answer too!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `java.util.Arrays.toString()` simple

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering about an `Array` convertion to a `String` is not that relevant because that would certainly depend on the output you are expecting.

Since you have not highlited it, the most straightforward way to ge a `String` literal out from an `Array` is to use the [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object%3aA-) method from `java.util` package.